# How to create a collection inside a collection in postman

Tags: postman

I have tried drag-dropping one request onto another but it doesn't work.

I expected this to work as moving a request from one collection to another can be achieved this way.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _a collection inside a collection_ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You can create Folders inside a collection

> Select a collection > Click on `View more actions` > Add folder

This is done mostly to group endpoints with similar functionality/ common initial routes.

Ex: `stackoverflow.com/questions`, `stackoverflow.com/questions/:questionId`

You can create more than one folder inside a collection.

[image]